# AWS Lambda (Python): Why do some compiled libraries need to be linked statically?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am using the python packages [psycopg2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2/2.6.1) and [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) (former PIL) in my lambda function. As far as I know, both need compiled system libraries ([libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq.html), [libjpeg](http://libjpeg-turbo.virtualgl.org/)).

I have installed the packages on an instance which was created from Amazon's Linux AMI to build the development package as suggested [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html).

*psycopg2* didn't work because [libpq.so had to be linked statically](https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2).

Can someone explain:

1. why *pillow* worked out of the box and
2. when a python library needs some extra tweaking to get it to work on lambda?

Comment: I run all my Lambda functions on Java but have noticed similar issues to what you're seeing with Python.  Generally speaking, you can't necessarily make assumptions about what libraries will be there for you and which ones won't.  The only way to know for sure is to play around with it at deployment time and act accordingly.  In the Java world, for example, if you use an S3 event to trigger your function the Eclipse Plug-in will automatically bundle the AWS SDK, all 35+ MB of it.  Why isn't it there already?  Dunno, it just isn't.